# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: arrays, loops, php

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [auth_id] => 1
            [auth_section] => Client Data Base
            [auth_parent_id] => 0
            [auth_admin] => 1
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [auth_id] => 2
                            [auth_section] => Client Contact
                            [auth_parent_id] => 1
                            [auth_admin] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [auth_id] => 6
            [auth_section] => All Back Grounds
            [auth_parent_id] => 0
            [auth_admin] => ,4
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [auth_id] => 7
                            [auth_section] => Edit Custom
                            [auth_parent_id] => 6
                            [auth_admin] => 1
                        )
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [auth_id] => 20
            [auth_section] => Order Mail
            [auth_parent_id] => 0
            [auth_admin] => 1
            [sub] => 
        )

}
```

When I process the sub inner array

```
for($in=0 ; $in < count($auth); $in++){

    $autsub     =   $auth[$in]["sub"];

    for($g=0 ; $g<count($autsub); $g++){

        echo $autsub[$g]["auth_id"];

    }
}
```

it shows this error

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array.........

how can I avoid that :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the last entry in the array (`2`) does not have a `sub` array, but you're trying to access it anyway. You'll need to check if the entry exists and if it's an array before looping over it. Here an example using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($array as $auth) {
    if (!empty($auth['sub']) && is_array($auth['sub'])) {
        foreach ($auth['sub'] as $sub) {
            if (!empty($sub['auth_id'])) {
                echo $sub['auth_id'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the offset type with the is_array() function. If you want a better answer, post the processing code.
Test if $auth[$in] and $autsub[$g] are arrays.