# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array on line 151

Tags: php, arrays

I have this piece of code, which works fine, but one of my clients are getting the

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

I commented the line that generates the error.

```
                                <?php 

                                $thumbId1 = get_field('portfolio_images'); //this is the line that generates the error



                                $portfolio_large = $thumbId1[0]['image'];

                                $mafioso_smvideo = get_field('small_video',$post->ID);



                                if($mafioso_smvideo!='') {

                                    echo do_shortcode($mafioso_smvideo);

                                }

                                elseif (!$portfolio_large == ''){ 

                                ?>

                                        <?php

                                            echo '<img src="'.aq_resize( $portfolio_large, 340, 197, true ).'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" class="categ-thumb"/>';

                                        ?>
```

Comment: Please post the get_field function.

Comment: this is a repeat question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059927/fatal-error-cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(is_array($thumbId1)){

$portfolio_large = $thumbId1[0]['image'];

}

?>
```